# Can I make different attribute for every vertex and every instance

Tags: javascript, 3d, webgl

When using `gl.drawArraysInstanced` I can use `gl.vertexAttribDivisor` and `stride` and `offset` to change the behavior how often a attribute changes, and I know what I can do with it.

But I want that the attribute changes for every vertex and every instance like so:

```js
// Vertex buffer
[
  vertex1,
  vertex2,
  vertex3,
]

// Color buffer
[
  color1,
  color2,
  color3,

  // Different colors for second triangle
  color4,
  color5,
  color6,
]

gl .bindBuffer (gl .ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBuffer);
gl .vertexAttribPointer (vertexLocation, 4, gl .FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
gl .enableVertexAttribArray (vertexLocation);

gl .bindBuffer (gl .ARRAY_BUFFER, colorBuffer);
gl .vertexAttribPointer (colorLocation, 4, gl .FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
gl .enableVertexAttribArray (colorLocation);

// What to do else with colorLocation.

gl .drawArraysInstanced (gl .TRIANGLES, 0, 3, 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have now used a FLOAT texture with the needed data in the vertex shader to get the desired results.